Cython wrapping - a class template - non-standard example
First, post. I'm sorry for any formatting errors. I'm working on porting a c++ project to a python. I cannot change the c++ code. Within this project, I'm working on porting a class template that depends on a bool as input to define the class. My various attempts at doing this has failed either where I simply don't have correct cython code or where I get error during cython's process of generating c++ code.  I haven't been able to solve my problem via other stack exchange posts [1] [2] [3] or via the documentation.
For my "best" attempt, I have something that looks like the following:
In the c++ header file foo.hh
class Foo{
public:
     static constexpr bool T
     Foo(Foo&& x) =  default;
     explicit Foo(const Foo<not T>&& x)
//Other methods and constructors not relevant.
}

The project I'm working with has multiple .pxdfile. The main file exposes the c++ code while the other .pxd files are for module specific tasks.
In main_decl.pxd
cdef cppclass Foo[T]
cdef cppclass Foo[T]:
    Foo(Foo& x)
    Foo(const Foo[T]&& x) #  I'm unsure if this is correct.
    #  other methods below

in the module specific file foo.pxd
from .main_decl cimport *

cdef class Foo:
    cdef Foo *thisptr

and finally the module itself Foo.pyx
# distutils: language = c++
cimport cython


cdef class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, T):  
        pass
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = NULL
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

In other parts of the project, the above pattern works for defining class. The error
main/foo.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/main/foo.o
      main/foo.cpp:1591:15: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
       1591 |   main::Foo<T>  *thisptr;
            |               ^~~
      main/Foo.cpp:1591:18: error: template argument 1 is invalid
       1591 |   main::Box<T>  *thisptr;

Any advice on this would be appreciated. I suspect this has something to do with how the template name T is used but am unsure of how to approach fixing this.

foo.hh is the original c++ code or generated? You ask to port a template, but there is no template in the c++ code only a couple of syntax errors.

and the error seems to be from code you do not show. Please try to create a [mcve]. Make a small toy project that has only the minimum to recreate the error, then post all of it here.

I guess the challenge is to correctly wrap a C++ template class Foo in cython in such a way python wrapper can handle both Foo<true> and Foo<false>.
foo.hh
#pragma once

template <bool T>
class Foo {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = T;

    Foo() {}
    Foo(Foo&& x) = default;
    explicit Foo(const Foo<!T>&& x) {}
};

C++ header defines a template class Foo that depends on a boolean. where you have Foo<true> and Foo<false> as different types.
main_decl.pxd
The C++ template specializations as separate classes:
cdef extern from "foo.hh" namespace "main":
    cdef cppclass FooTrue "Foo<true>":
        Foo()
        Foo(FooTrue& x)
        Foo(const FooFalse&& x)

    cdef cppclass FooFalse "Foo<false>":
        Foo()
        Foo(FooFalse& x)
        Foo(const FooTrue&& x)

FooTrue is cython representation of Foo<true>, and FooFalse is for Foo<false>. That ensures the template argument is handled correctly.
foo.pxd
here you create Cython wrapper classes for the two C++ classes:
from .main_decl cimport FooTrue, FooFalse

cdef class PyFooTrue:
    cdef FooTrue* thisptr

cdef class PyFooFalse:
    cdef FooFalse* thisptr

PyFooTrue and PyFooFalse are classes that hold pointers to the C++ Foo<true> and Foo<false> objects.
Foo.pyx
PyFoo determines whether to use Foo<true> or Foo<false> based on the boolean T (at runtime):
from .foo cimport FooTrue, FooFalse  # import the classes

cdef class PyFoo:
    cdef FooTrue* thisptr_true
    cdef FooFalse* thisptr_false
    cdef bint is_true

    def __init__(self, bint T):
        if T:
            self.thisptr_true = new FooTrue()  # the correct class
            self.is_true = True
        else:
            self.thisptr_false = new FooFalse()  # the correct class
            self.is_true = False

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self.is_true:
            del self.thisptr_true
        else:
            del self.thisptr_false

depending on the boolean T, either FooTrue or FooFalse is instantiated. The C++ object is created and destroyed correctly.
setup.py
for Building the Extension:
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools.extension import Extension

extensions = [
    Extension(
        name="foo.Foo",  # the package structure
        sources=["foo/Foo.pyx"],  # source path
        include_dirs=["foo", "."],  # include necessary directories
        language="c++",
    )
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)



Thanks. This pattern seems to be the right path where I was stuck with.
